# AWS MongoDB inbound rules for replica cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I am using AWS for my MEAN stack servers. I have three nodes for NodeJS instances and also three instances for MongoDB clusters running as replica set mode.
To secure MongoDB inbound request I want to configure security group for mongo instances as below:

1. Inbound allowed for NodeJS instances so that node instances can make connection to database
2. Inbound allowed for MongoDB instances so that each of mongo instances can talk to each other for replication

I am facing following problems:

1. In screen to edit, inbound rules have only fields for IP Address. As I need to set custom IP, how can I provide 3+2 five instances in one text box? Since I can't even simple range as all five IP Address are different and can't fit into range sequence.
2. What will happen if IP address changes? Do I need to use Elastic IP or I can use instances hostname?

Please, advice.

Answer (score 0):

For answer to the **first question**:

If the IPs of each instance are in a pattern (I'm pretty sure they will) then you should be using [CIDR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) representation of the IP address.

So consider you have 5 IPs from `192.168.1.14` to `192.168.1.18` then your CIDR can be any of the following:

```
192.168.1.14/31
192.168.1.16/31
192.168.1.18/32
```

You can put any of the values there in your **IP Range** field in the edit screen.

There are various online converters out there like [this](http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr). You can use any one of them.

For answer to the **second question**:

The internal IP of the Amazon instances generally do not changes if you are within the same virtual network so you can use the internal IPs of your network (like I used in the example). Or if your IPs are fluctuating then yes, you have to use the static IP or elastic IPs for the same.

Comment: Unfortunately all of my six nodes IP Address are not in pattern at all.

Comment: when I used online tool for my set of IPs then I got range of CIDR. I need only one CIDR so that I can update in AWS rule.